# Ошибка при компиляции кода в MinGW

Tags: c, cmd, компиляция, mingw

Решил изучать программирование. Решил первым языком начать изучать "C". Редактор выбрал - sublime text 3. Установил на компьютер MinGW. В cmd вбиваю команду для компиляции моего кода - 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но пишет что "gcc" не является внутренней или внешней
командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом.
Хотя в среду Path я внес -
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
 В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: А сам gcc точно стоит? Файл  gcc.exe есть в пути?

Comment: да, вроде оно - https://imgur.com/a/hZln2

Comment: А после занесения дополнительного пути в PATH вы свое окно cmd перезапускали?

Comment: Во общем, помогло что то из этого(я это делал)) ): выход/заход в систему, переустановка MinGW, запуск cmd через выполнить а не ярлык на раб. столе, у меня была среда Path (но не большими буквами) - сделал на большие буквы убрал лишнее (%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps), поставил только путь к mingw\bin, вернул обратно лишнее, и сработало))